# Android gallery child fill width

Tags: android, android-gallery

I want to make a listview that items can be swipeable, I already tried `swipelistview` but that's not very fluid for me, so I thought about using the gallery, the actual problem here is that the children of this gallery are not filling the whole width, what I need is this:

first item of the gallery is a layout, at this point you can't tell that this is a gallery it's like a simple layout, but once you swipe it it moves to the next child

is there a way to do this 
thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, i solved it by setting the minWidth of the child to 10000, this makes it fill the whole width